# SQL Aggregate Woes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this code:

```
SELECT q.HospitalNumber, q.Patient_Name, 
q.[Date/Time]) as DATE_OF_GCS,    --convert(varchar(5),q.[Date/Time],108) as TIME_OF_GCS,

max(q.[GCS_COUNT]) as BEST_GCS

From
(
Select pat.HospitalNumber, pat.FirstName + ' ' + pat.LastName as Patient_Name, ts.Time as [Date/Time], sum(pt.value) as [GCS_COUNT]
from ParametersText pt INNER JOIN TextSignals ts ON ts.TextID = pt.TextID AND ts.ParameterID = pt.ParameterID
INNER JOIN Patients pat ON pat.patientID = ts.PatientID
WHERE ts.ParameterID = 21654 or ts.ParameterID = 21655 or ts.ParameterID = 21656
GROUP BY pat.HospitalNumber, pat.FirstName, pat.LastName, ts.PatientID, ts.Time

) q

GROUP BY q.HospitalNumber, q.Patient_Name, q.[Date/Time]
--,convert(varchar(5),q.[Date/Time],108)
```

But all I'm after is the highest Best_GCS per day per patient, but I need the time as well. The recording of the GCS can occur many times of the day and can be the same score several times. Any help would be most appreciated...

Thanks very much in advance...

This is on SQL Server (t-sql)

Here is a snippet of the data this query throws out:

```
patientID Patient_Name DATE_OF_GCS GCS
442 patient name 2014-02-13 16:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-13 18:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-13 20:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 04:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 05:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 06:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 08:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 12:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 16:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 17:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 20:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-14 23:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 00:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 02:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 05:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 08:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 12:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 15:00:00.000 11
442 patient name 2014-02-15 16:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 17:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 18:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-15 20:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-16 00:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-16 02:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-16 05:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-16 08:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-16 20:00:00.000 11
442 patient name 2014-02-16 20:51:00.000 4
442 patient name 2014-02-17 01:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 02:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 04:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 06:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 08:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 10:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 15:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 18:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-17 20:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 00:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 04:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 08:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 12:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 14:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 15:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 17:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 19:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-18 20:00:00.000 11
442 patient name 2014-02-19 02:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-19 06:00:00.000 15
442 patient name 2014-02-19 09:00:00.000 15
471 patient name 2014-02-13 09:00:00.000 7
471 patient name 2014-02-13 11:00:00.000 7
471 patient name 2014-02-13 13:00:00.000 7
471 patient name 2014-02-13 15:00:00.000 8
471 patient name 2014-02-13 17:00:00.000 8
471 patient name 2014-02-13 19:00:00.000 7
471 patient name 2014-02-13 21:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-13 22:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 00:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 02:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 04:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 06:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 08:00:00.000 9
471 patient name 2014-02-14 10:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-14 12:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-14 14:00:00.000 8
471 patient name 2014-02-14 16:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-14 18:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-14 20:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-14 22:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 00:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 02:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 04:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 06:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 08:00:00.000 8
471 patient name 2014-02-15 09:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 10:00:00.000 6
471 patient name 2014-02-15 11:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 13:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-15 14:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 16:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 18:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 19:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 21:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-15 22:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 00:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 02:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 02:30:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 03:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 06:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 08:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 12:00:00.000 5
471 patient name 2014-02-16 14:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 18:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 19:00:00.000 3
471 patient name 2014-02-16 21:00:00.000 3
472 patient name 2014-02-13 08:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-13 12:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-13 15:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-13 19:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-13 22:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 03:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 08:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 14:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 17:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 19:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 21:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-14 23:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-15 01:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-15 05:00:00.000 14
472 patient name 2014-02-15 07:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-15 08:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-15 20:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-15 22:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 00:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 03:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 05:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 07:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 09:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 12:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 15:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 18:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 20:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-16 22:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-17 00:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-17 02:00:00.000 15
472 patient name 2014-02-17 04:00:00.000 15
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks Anyway..

Here's the code. If there's any way it could be better, I'd love to hear it:

```
With t as 
(
SELECT q.HospitalNumber, q.Patient_Name, 
q.[Date/Time] as DATE_OF_GCS, 

 max(q.[GCS_COUNT]) as BEST_GCS

From
(
    Select pat.HospitalNumber, pat.FirstName + ' ' + pat.LastName as Patient_Name, ts.Time as [Date/Time], sum(pt.value) as [GCS_COUNT]
    from ParametersText pt INNER JOIN TextSignals ts ON ts.TextID = pt.TextID AND ts.ParameterID = pt.ParameterID
    INNER JOIN Patients pat ON pat.patientID = ts.PatientID
    WHERE ts.ParameterID = 21654 or ts.ParameterID = 21655 or ts.ParameterID = 21656
    GROUP BY pat.HospitalNumber, pat.FirstName, pat.LastName, ts.PatientID, ts.Time
) q 



GROUP BY q.HospitalNumber, q.Patient_Name, q.[Date/Time]
)

Select hospitalnumber, Date_Of_GCS, Best_GCS
FROM (
select t.hospitalnumber, t.Date_Of_GCS, t.Best_GCS, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.hospitalnumber, cast(t.Date_Of_GCS as date) order by t.Best_GCS Desc ) as GCS
FROM t ) as p
where gcs = 1
Order By hospitalnumber, Date_Of_GCS
```